# eregi_replace problem!

Tags: php, regex, posix

now i have an eregi_replace Problem:

I have this

```
$subject = "This is for @codeworxx - you have to try first!";
$text = eregi_replace('(((@))[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)','<a href="http://www.google.de/\\1">\\1</a>', $subject);
echo $text;
```

Everything works fine, but the

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/@codeworxx">@codeworxx</a>
```

but i want this one:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/codeworxx">codeworxx</a>
```

how to do?

Thanks,
Sascha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$subject = "This is for @codeworxx - you have to try first!";
$text = eregi_replace('@([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)','<a href="http://www.google.de/\\1">\\1</a>', $subject);
echo $text;
```

Comment: All of the ereg_* functions have been deprecated in PHP5.3 and they'll be gone in PHP6.  You should use the preg_* functions instead.